# Do we really need the "untagged" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags

Currently, there are 8 questions that are tagged [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Those 8 can easily be edited to no longer include the tag [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), but I would argue that it should be destroyed altogether. I am having a hard time imaging a question that I couldn't find a single tag for in our [4 pages of tags](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular), but would still be an on topic question for this site.

What is the consensus on this? Are there valid cases for the [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag?

Comment: I feel that the "untagged" tag is something from the beggining of the site and for some reason it is still there. This is only my guess. I am not responsible to know that. But, as I can see the list, most of the 8 questions belong to "data-request" tag and yes, I think it could be edited to remove the "untagged" and add another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is automatically assigned when questions are migrated from other sites to Open Data, and all those questions should be tagged appropriately.  There is no valid use case to tag a new or existing question with [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Secondly, [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is assigned if all tags on a question are deleted.  This can happen because [tags that only have a single question are automatically deleted after six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167880/172266).  In this case, too, the community should assign appropriate tags to those questions.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the purpose of this tag.

Comment: I've gone through the site and removed the untagged and introduced tags as appropriate.  Thanks for the clarification!