# Untagged Tag and Edits

Tags: support, tags

I went to [edit the spelling in this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13788/are-there-any-open-data-sets-for-software-clasification) and ran into a conundrum.
You cannot make an edit to a question with the "untagged" tag, without modifying the tags.
Is that the correct behavior?
I see that [untagged](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/do-we-really-need-the-untagged-tag) is a carryover from other sites...this is unfortunate.
I feel like other sites already dump their baggage here, now we have to come up with tags for them?
Perhaps the answer is to make the question have tags coming over vs. a very un-useful and bothersome tag that forces us to have to do more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended.

Questions shouldn't be untagged and the [untagged](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag counts as no tags, so we require that any edits to a post that is untagged include a new tag so that the question can be properly sorted. Just as you would retag a question that was asked here but mis-tagged, so too you should maintain the quality of the site by editing the tags on migrated questions to be certain they are appropriate.

Questions arrive here "untagged" when a the question is migrated from a site and the tags on the question don't exist on the target site. For sites with migration paths (you don't have any), user-driven migrations require that at least one tag currently on the question exists on the target site. When a moderator from a site migrates a question, however, there is no such requirement, so you will occasionally end up with untagged questions. All migrations to this site must be moderator-initiated.

The tags on this [particular question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44170/are-there-any-open-data-sets-for-software-clasification) were "dataset" and "multilabel-classification". Neither of these exist here, so the question was left untagged.

There are a couple of issues with requiring moderators to fix tags before they migrate, though:

1. The moderators may not know the appropriate tags to use.
2. The appropriate tags may not exist on the originating site, so they *can't* add them.
3. The moderators may not have an account on the target site so that they can edit the tags to be correct.

It's quite common for all three to be the case, even!

[Over the last 90 days, 17 questions have been migrated to this site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (link requires [2k reputation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) and only one has been rejected. If these questions are a poor fit for Open Data, please work to downvote and close them! If they are on topic and reasonable, cultivate them as you would any question asked here initially by editing and retagging them as appropriate.

If you have a consistent problem of poor quality questions being migrated here from a particular site, please flag one of them for moderator attention and point it out to your mods. They can reach out to the moderators on the other sites to work out some guidance on good questions to migrate.

Comment: if questions shouldn't be untagged, then why are they allowed to come from another site untagged. whomever is bringing them over should be doing the tagging.  its also really bizarre that stackoverflow has you moderators out here with zero community engagement. same thing with dude who shared the annual review. appreciate it, but we have no clue who you are. and its not like you can be bothered to introduce yourself.

Comment: essentially, you are saying other people don't know so that puts the work on us. i feel like if you are putting the work on us anyways with porting the question over, you can do some of the work yourself. particularly how questions get dumped here from data science and gis. there is zero thought put into it and the mods are more than happy to get rid of the questions and dump there here.

Comment: i also truly dislike how you moderators are going about answering questions. we have much older questions on this site that could use answering.

Comment: Apologies for not introducing myself. I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?) here - the newest, in fact, having just started in July and only a week ago come back from three months off for maternity leave. Apologies for our attentiveness seeming spotty. We're working on initiatives to be more active on metas around the network to make sure that y'all feel supported. I'll be going through questions asked over time everywhere but if you have any specific ones, link me to them.

Comment: The information I'm conveying here is just how the system works. While I do explain why the system is the way it is, we're always open to revisiting that if it's causing harm. About half of the seventeen questions migrated here were untagged when they arrived, meaning about 8-9 questions in three months. To me, this doesn't seem overly onerous to address. If it is for y'all, I do suggest some solutions in the answer, too. Retagging migrated questions isn't something I've seen widespread complaints about, though, so changing the behavior hasn't been a priority.

Comment: i appreciate the info, and your comments/answers in general. also, good food for thought when comparing to other sites.